# Display text according to a choice in drop-down list

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to display a text according to a choice that I made in choice list with excel.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you mean a dropdown list.

Below is some information on creating and using one. Hope this helps. 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-drop-down-list-7693307A-59EF-400A-B769-C5402DCE407B